# How to escape tab characters in a string passed to SetWindowText()

Tags: mfc, escaping

I want to change the text of my status bar:

```
pView->m_pWndStatusBar->SetWindowText( _T("Refreshing...\t\tFiltered") );
```

The above code is not accepting the escape character `\t`.

The output is:

```
Refreshing...
```

Expected output:

```
Refreshing...[tab][tab]Filtered
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633546.aspx) you cannot use tabs in strings passed to `SetWindowText`:

> The **SetWindowText** function does not expand tab characters (ASCII code 0x09).

I recommend to use spaces instead of tabs in your status bar.

In case you want to use tabs to align text of a different control (e.g. `CStatic`) then I recommend to use an additional control. The original control gets the text before the tab and the new control gets the text after the tab. Then you can align the controls to each other as you like.